# Edit form checkbox, radio and trix editor not getting pre-populated in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, formtastic

I have a form which has checkboxes, trix editor, radio button and text fields. When I edit the record in admin interface, form is shown with all text fields. Am not able to see trix editor, checkboxes and radio buttons.

I know `as: :radio` and `as: :check_boxes` and `as: :trix_editor` should work but they are not getting pre populated with already saved values

Here is my jobposting.rb file.

Any help will be really appreciated.

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs "New Job Posting" do
      f.input :title
      f.input :description, as: :trix_editor
      f.input :how_to_apply, as: :trix_editor
      f.input :job_type, as: :radio
      f.input :city
      f.input :user_id
      f.input :categories, as: :check_boxes

      f.input :publish


    end
    f.actions
  end
```

and the form appears like this

[image]

Its  not showing the fields(**description, how to apply**) which should have trix editor. For radio(**Job Type**) and check box(**Categories**) fields its showing simple yes and no..where as the actual values for these fields are these[image]

**EDITED**

```
Started GET "/admin/job_postings/3/edit" for ::1 at 2017-02-11 12:41:22 +0530
Processing by Admin::JobPostingsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  AdminUser Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  JobPosting Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "job_postings".* FROM "job_postings" WHERE "job_postings"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "job_postings".* FROM "job_postings" WHERE "job_postings"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "3"]]
  Rendered /Users/KrishnaTeja/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-2bb5021f81c2/app/views/active_admin/resource/edit.html.arb (270.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 367ms (ActiveRecord: 7.4ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `categories' for #<Class:0x007ffdd084e420>):
    1: insert_tag renderer_for(:edit)
  app/admin/job_postings.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
  app/admin/job_postings.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'


  Rendered /Users/KrishnaTeja/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (16.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/KrishnaTeja/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (7.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/KrishnaTeja/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/KrishnaTeja/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (115.2ms)
```

[image][image]

This is my `views/job_postings/_form.html.erb`
*if you check the categories field its not coming from any table am having an array and iterating through it.*

```
<%= form_for @job_posting do |f| %>
<% if @job_posting.errors.any? %>
        <div id="errors">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@job_posting.errors.count, "error") %> prevented this post from saving:</h2>
            <ul>
                <% @job_posting.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

<p>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :description %>

   <%= f.trix_editor :description %>

</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :how_to_apply %>
    <%= f.trix_editor :how_to_apply %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :categories %>

    <% [ 'Front End', 'Back End', 'Others'].each do |category| %>
      <%= label_tag "job_posting_categories_#{category}", category %>

      <%= check_box_tag "job_posting[categories][]", category, checked(category), id: "job_posting_categories_#{category}" %> 


    <% end %>

</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :job_type %>
    <% [ 'FullTime', 'Contract', 'PartTime', 'Freelance', 'Intern'].each do |job_type| %>
         <%= f.radio_button 'job_type', job_type %>
          <%= job_type.humanize %>
    <% end %>

</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :city %>
    <%= f.text_field :city %>
</p>
    <%= f.submit "Post Job" %>


<% end %>
```

Comment: Could you please post the code with the `check_boxes` and `radio` and such in there, because as you have it posted right now, what is being rendered is working perfectly. We need to see the code as you want it, and the resulting screen shot

Comment: @LBarry I added more info. Sorry for not being precise.

Comment: @KrishnaTejaKarnam: we prefer answers to go in the answer box here. Would you copy it to a self-answer, and then roll back your question to its latest state prior to adding in the solution? Thank you.

Comment: @halfer I have added. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

```
ActiveAdmin.register JobPosting do

# See permitted parameters documentation:
# https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters
#
permit_params :title, :description,:how_to_apply, :job_type ,:city,:user_id,{ categories: []}, :publish
#
# or
#
# permit_params do
#   permitted = [:permitted, :attributes]
#   permitted << :other if params[:action] == 'create' && current_user.admin?
#   permitted
# end


form do |f|
    inputs "New Job Posting" do

      input :title
      input :description
      input :how_to_apply
      input :job_type, as: :radio, collection: [ 'FullTime', 'Contract', 'PartTime', 'Freelance', 'Intern']
      input :city
      input :user, member_label: :email
      input :categories, as: :check_boxes, collection: ['Front End','Back End','Others'].map { |e| [e, e,{checked: f.object.categories.include?(e)}] }

      input :publish


    end
    actions
  end


end
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that `trix_editor` is not compatible with activeadmin, so I'm not sure if you will be able to use that at all. For the others, you need to include a collection for it to display, otherwise it appears to default to yes/no boxes. So something like this:

```
f.input :categories, as: :check_boxes, collection: f.object.categories
```

That should let active admin know that you want to use the options available to categories to populate the checkboxes.

EDITED:

Try this instead:

```
  form do |f|
    inputs "New Job Posting" do
      input :title
      input :description
      input :how_to_apply
      input :job_type, as: :radio
      input :city
      input :user_id
      input :categories, as: :check_boxes, collection: f.object.categories
      input :publish
    end
    actions
  end
```

or even:

```
  form do |f|
    inputs "New Job Posting" do
      input :title
      input :description
      input :how_to_apply
      input :job_type, as: :radio
      input :city
      input :user_id
      input :categories, as: :check_boxes, collection: JobPosting.categories
      input :publish
    end
    actions
  end
```

Comment: I have added this `f.input :categories, as: :check_boxes, collection: f.object.categories` and I get this error `undefined method "map" for "[\"Front End\", \"Back End\"]":String` looks like something related to type casting. I dont know if its a silly thing am missing.

Comment: You will probably need to remove the `f` from the collection, so instead use `collection: object.categories`

Comment: even then am getting the same error `undefined method "map" for "[\"Front End\", \"Back End\"]":String`

Comment: I edited my answer to hopefully fix that. If my edit doesn't work, please post the full stack trace on that error you received, it is not one I have ever seen before.

Comment: I have added the stack trace and some screenshots too. Can you kindly check them.

Comment: I have added the solution.

Comment: @KrishnaTejaKarnam: it is not mandatory, but it is a good way of thanking people to upvote their work, even if you prefer to accept/tick your own solution. If you wish to do so, click the up arrow adjacent to answers that you thought were good or deserve gratitude. Thanks.